# How to set up prepared query using IN statement

Tags: wpdb, sql

I am a tad bit confused on how I would set up a SQL IN statement using a prepared query. Here is the code:

```
$in = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($product_ids), '%d'));
        $results = $this->db->get_results($this->db->prepare("SELECT ID, post_title FROM {$this->db->posts} WHERE ID NOT IN({$in}) AND post_type=%s ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT %d", array(implode(',', $product_ids), "post", $num)));
```

The result returns null. Where am I wrong?

UPDATE: Fixed my own problem. Here is my solution for anyone wondering:

```
$prepare = array();
        $in = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($product_ids), '%d'));
        foreach ($product_ids as $ids){
            $prepare[] = $ids;   
        }
        $prepare[] = "post";
        $prepare[] = $num;
        $results = $this->db->get_results($this->db->prepare("SELECT ID, post_title FROM {$this->db->posts} WHERE ID NOT IN({$in}) AND post_type=%s ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT %d", $prepare));
```

Comment: Please add your solution as _answer_. Answering your own question is something that we encourage you to do.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the problem:

```
$prepare = array();
        $in = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($product_ids), '%d'));
        foreach ($product_ids as $ids){
            $prepare[] = $ids;   
        }
        $prepare[] = "post";
        $prepare[] = $num;
        $results = $this->db->get_results($this->db->prepare("SELECT ID, post_title FROM {$this->db->posts} WHERE ID NOT IN({$in}) AND post_type=%s ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT %d", $prepare));
```